# Where to get the JRE binaries/zip for Windows x64bit?

Tags: download, java

Where can I get the JRE binaries/zip for Windows x64bit machine?

I searched on Oracle Java achieve  [here](http://goo.gl/4tVb), but I got the .exes installer files

or

Is it the right thing to copy the installed directories/files by the jre installer?

I am actually packaging JRE along with Tomcat for distribution of webapp.

Comment: hum, I only see the installers too. Perhaps the exe also performs other tasks, like adding registry entries, or the control panel section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need a zip file, it is possible to install the JDK or JRE using the installer and package the resulting directory afterwards as a zip.

But that will leave you with just a JVM, no control applet, no automatic JAVA_HOME and so on..

Comment: i am actually packaging JRE along with Tomcat and i am setting all the environment variable from tomcat itself 
Will this be affected, by using files as you told?

Comment: This can be used in the context you mentioned.

Answer (score 2):

The JDK and JRE are never distributed as zips, but always as an installer. This is because there is executable code (`unpack200` in particular) that has to be run as part of the installation.